# JavaScript Typing Effect Function

Tags: javascript, function, settimeout

I'm trying to write a JS function that takes one argument, txt and prints it letter by letter, I already have a code, but when I try to 'convert' it as a function it stops working. Any ideas?

```
var myText = "Text to be displayed";    
var myArray = myText.split("");    
var loopTimer;

function frameLooper() {    
    if(myArray.length > 0) {    
        document.getElementById("type_text").innerHTML += myArray.shift();    
    } else {
        clearTimeout(loopTimer);
        return false;
    }
    loopTimer = setTimeout("frameLooper()",70);
}
frameLooper();
```

Typing effect function:

```
var i;
var speed = 120;

function typeWriter(txt) {
  for (i=0;i<=txt.length - 1;i++)
  {
    document.getElementById("type_text").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}
typeWriter("text to be typed");
```

Comment: what exactly is not working, please add more details

Comment: In the second code, you are not passing the variables to the function called by setTimeout. Use `setTimeout(typeWriter, speed, variableToBePassed);`

Comment: fwiw - https://codepen.io/geoffgraham/pen/jrWwWM - you can do this in pure CSS.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the original text to the function in `setTimeout`, as well as remove the loop over the entire text, that you are calling in each `setTimeout` callback (which makes it print the entire text in each callback).

As an enhancement, I would suggest passing the index in the function calls as well.

```js
const SPEED = 120;

function typeWriter(txt, i = 0) {
  document.getElementById("type_text").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
  
  // check if the entire text has been typed
  if (i < txt.length - 1) {
    // pass function with the text and the index (+1)
    setTimeout(() => typeWriter(txt, i + 1), SPEED);
  }
}
typeWriter("text to be typed");
```

```html
<p id="type_text"></p>
```

Comment: I think you have to check whether `i<txt.length-1` before calling `setTimeout`

Answer (score 1):

It's easier with promises and `async`:

```js
let delay = n => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, n));

async function typeWriter(div, txt) {
  for (let char of txt) {
    div.innerHTML += char;
    await delay(200);
  }
}

typeWriter(document.querySelector('#type'), 'hello there')
```

```html
<div id="type"></div>
```